# Git working tree set false

Tags: git, head

Hy @ all, i have a big problem. 
I´m relative new to git so i really need your help. 
Through some false commands (i didn´t remember yet) and lots of tryings to rest the problem my working tree is false in my git. 
Now it looks like the following

```
 62efde2 (origin/development, development) hilfe

| * d90d66a (origin/beach, beach) auskommentieren ausgabe bewerb

|/

| * 930e0cf (refs/stash) WIP on development: f1d1bf4 beach-bilder

|/

| * 6f2288f (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) updated gitignore

| * d40a15e Initial Commit
```

But development should inherit the master. So it should be like

```
 - Master
    * Development
    * Beach
```

I hope you can help me pl! Thank you

Comment: According to your tree, development and beach are both descendants of master. The root of the tree is at the bottom.

Comment: [Better List][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T99Ih.jpg

But then development is not on master? And i have to edit my question: Development inherit from master and beach from development